# index on query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am trying to work out what columns and a combination of indexes may be useful for optimising this query. I think wine.vid, vineyard.vid, wine.cid, class.cid and grade would be the important columns but I am unsure about how to go about generating the combined indexes.

```
Select vintage, wine_no, wname, 
       pctalc, grade, price, wine.vid, vname, wine.cid, cname 
from vineyard, class, wine 
where wine.vid = vineyard.vid 
  and wine.cid = class.cid
  and wine.cid = 'SHIRAZ' 
  and grade = 'A';
```

Here are what the tables look like in case that's important.

```
CREATE TABLE  VINEYARD                                                 
      (VID           CHAR(12) NOT NULL,                                 
       PID           CHAR(08) NOT NULL,                                 
       RID           CHAR(12) NOT NULL,                                 
       VNAME         CHAR(45) NOT NULL,                    
       VMANAGER      CHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
       COMMENTS      CHAR(300),    
       PRIMARY KEY  (VID),                                              
       FOREIGN KEY  (PID)                                          
       REFERENCES    PRODUCER,                                                  
       FOREIGN KEY  (RID)                                              
       REFERENCES    REGION);

CREATE TABLE  WINE                                                    
      (VINTAGE       NUMBER(4)   NOT NULL,                                
       WINE_NO       INTEGER     NOT NULL,                                        
       VID           CHAR(12)    NOT NULL,                                
       CID           CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,                                
       PCTALC        NUMBER(4,2),                                          
       PRICE         NUMBER(6,2),                                          
       GRADE         CHAR(01)    NOT NULL,                                
       WNAME         CHAR(40)    NOT NULL,                   
       COMMENTS      CHAR(300),        
       PRIMARY KEY  (VINTAGE,                                           
                     WINE_NO),                                                
       FOREIGN KEY  (VID)                                               
       REFERENCES    VINEYARD,                                                  
       FOREIGN KEY  (CID)                                               
       REFERENCES    CLASS);

CREATE TABLE  CLASS                                                     
      (CID           CHAR(10) NOT NULL,                                 
       CNAME         CHAR(45) NOT NULL,                    
       COLOUR        CHAR(05),     
       PRIMARY KEY  (CID));
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a basic example for your needs, I try to explain that indexes should be optimized first for the where and join conditions.  Secondarily on any group by. Last is Order by.  By having multiple indexes on a single table by their individual columns does not really help as much as a better constructed.  Also note, it is best to always include `table.column` or `alias.column` so nobody has to guess which table a column is coming from.  Using aliases that closely match context of the table's purpose also helps shorten writing and readability.  Ex: "W" for "Wine", "V" for Vineyard, "C" for Class.

```
Select 
      w.vintage, 
      w.wine_no, 
      w.wname, 
      w.pctalc, 
      w.grade, 
      w.price, 
      w.vid, 
      v.vname, 
      w.cid, 
      c.cname 
   from 
      wine w
         JOIN vineyard v
            on w.vid = v.vid
         JOIN class c
            on w.cid = c.cid
   where
          w.grade = 'A'
      and w.cid = 'SHIRAZ'
```

So, now lets look at the indexing.  Since Wine is the primary table and the vineyard and class are secondary lookups, lets look at the WHERE first...  You are filtering on WINE for the class 'SHIRAZ' AND grade 'A', these will BOTH be first positions in the index.  Next is your join conditions to the lookup tables, so I would include those as well.  By having these components in the index, the engine can use them instead of having to go to the actual data pages before doing the join.  Only when all parts are covered does it actually go to the data pages to retrieve what is qualified for.  So your index should be

```
Table      Index
Wine       (grade, cid, vid )
vineyard   (vid, vname )
class      (cid, cname )
```

For the secondary lookup tables, you can see the primary field (first position) of the index is the ID of the table, but since you are only grabbing the name description from that table, having a "covering" index will help in the same way.  Again, the engine will never need to go back to the raw data pages.

I'm sure you dont have millions of records like some larger databases, but understanding the context and optimization approach is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

For beginning, create 5 indexes as

```
create index i1_wine_vid on wine (vid);
create index i2_wine_cid on wine (cid);
create index i3_wine_gra on wine (grade);
create index i1_vine_vid on vineyard (vid);
create index i1_clas_cid on class (cid);
```

Collect statistics for tables and indexes, check explain plan, run the query and see how it behaves.

---

Not that it matters much regarding your question, but: you should always use table aliases when referencing columns. Try to avoid naming all tables in `FROM` clause, separated by comma and then *joining* them in `WHERE` clause - use `JOIN`s, leave `WHERE` for conditions. Something like this:

```
SELECT w.vintage,
       w.wine_no,
       w.wname,
       w.pctalc,
       w.grade,
       w.price,
       w.vid,
       v.vname,
       w.cid,
       c.cname
  FROM vineyard v
       JOIN wine w ON w.vid = v.vid
       JOIN class c ON c.cid = w.cid
 WHERE     w.cid = 'SHIRAZ'
       AND w.grade = 'A';
```